# ROQL Group By Combine Fields

Tags: roql

I'm using Oracle RightNow which uses MySQL but can't have nested queries and only a select (pun!) number of commands at my disposal: http://documentation.custhelp.com/euf/assets/devdocs/august2016/Connect_PHP/Content/Connect%20for%20PHP%20API/RightNow%20Object%20Query%20Language/ROQL%20and%20Common%20Objects.htm

**CASE statements are not permitted**

Let's say I have

```
Select Count(*) as Amount, Category 
From MyTable
Group by Category
```

All is well and I get a table as below

```
Amount | Category
---------------------
1      | Contact Editor
4      | Incident Editor
787    | Raise a Request
78     | Pending Information
```

How would I need to amend my query so I could combine the first two rows to have a new updated table as

```
Amount | Category
---------------------
5      | Editor
787    | Raise a Request
78     | Pending Information
```

Thanks

Comment: What is behind logic ?  what relations have  the first two rows ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze I guess both have Editor string in Category

Comment: Specifically one is "Contact Editor" and one is "Incident Editor" - we want to capture them two as just being under "Editor"

Answer (score 1):

Try grouping using `case` expression:

```
select Count(*) as Amount,  case when Category in('Contact Editor', 'Incident Editor') then 'editor' else Category end
From MyTable
Group by case when Category in('Contact Editor', 'Incident Editor') then 'editor' else Category end
```

Comment: 99% there but it turns out case statements are not permitted!

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*), 
case when Category like '%Editor' then 'Editor' else Category end as Category
From MyTable
Group by Category
```

Comment: 99% there but it turns out case statements are not permitted!

Comment: who doesn't permit them?

Comment: http://documentation.custhelp.com/euf/assets/devdocs/august2016/Connect_PHP/Content/Connect%20for%20PHP%20API/RightNow%20Object%20Query%20Language/ROQL%20and%20Common%20Objects.htm

Comment: this is the first time in my life I hear about this thing. This is not MySQL, this is not even close to MySQL.

If I were you, I'd do the sum at the application level, which I assume is written in PHP. I'm not even sure it's possible to do it in ROQL